# addition operator has no affect

Tags: c++

I am trying to add two floats in a for loop and its telling me '+' has no affect.  I am attempting to make it parse through each incrememnt (.25) of the two ranges (begrate and endrate) (1 and 2) and 1+.25 is not working correctly and I get an infinite loop

```
float begrate,endrate,inc,year=0;

cout << "Monthly Payment Factors used in Compute Monthly Payments!" << endl;
cout << "Enter Interest Rate Range and Increment" << endl;
cout << "Enter the Beginning of the Interest Range:  ";
cin >> begrate;
cout << "Enter the Ending of the Interest Range:  ";
cin >> endrate;
cout << "Enter the Increment of the Interest Range:  ";
cin >> inc;
cout << "Enter the Year Range in Years:  ";
cin >> year;

cout << endl;

for (float i=1;i<year;i++){
    cout << "Year:  " << "     ";
    for(begrate;begrate<endrate;begrate+inc){
        cout << "Test " << begrate << endl;
    }
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: `a+b` doesn't modify `a` (or `b`). It makes logical sense. There is a set of compound assignment operators that do affect `a`.

Comment: You probably want to use begrate+=inc instead of begrate+inc

Comment: Also do you really want year to be a float? If someone types 1.5 you will not get the desired answer using this calculation.

Comment: I wouldn't want i to be a float either. using a float in a for loop isn't a good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use += instead of +, as this will set `begrate` to `begrate+inc`. The better solution would be to have a temporary loop variable that starts equal to begrate then increment it.

```
for (float i=1;i<year;i++){
    cout << "Year:  " << "     ";
    for(float j = begrate;j<endrate;j+=inc){
        cout << "Test " << j << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I should have caught that on my own!

Answer (score 7):

That's because begrate+inc has no effect on the value of begrate.  The + operator is not like the ++ operator.  You must assign the results to something to have an effect.  What you wanted is this:

```
begrate = begrate + inc
```

Or

```
begrate += inc
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Just replace the following line

for(begrate;begrate<endrate;begrate+inc){


with

for(begrate;begrate<endrate;begrate+=inc){
```

notice the begrate**+=**inc here